# This is my Elastic Search 2.3.1 code : Transport client error

Tags: elasticsearch

> TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new
>   InetSocketTransportAddress(searchConfiguration.getHost(),
>   searchConfiguration.getPort())

but I get error at

> searchConfiguration.getHost(), searchConfiguration.getPort()

How to pass these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
TransportClient.builder().build()
    .addTransportAddress(
    new InetSocketTransportAddress(
    InetAddress.getByName(
    searchConfiguration.getHost()),
    searchConfiguration.getPort()))
</code>
```